# Show processing sequence of formulas in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to show the sequence in which formulas are processed in a Excel-sheet with many complex formulas?
In my case this is important because the formulas have dependencies to each other and I need to find out the sequence in which the formulas could be processed one after another.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel dynamically adjusts the calculation sequence in such a way as to resolve the dependencies, and normally only recalculates the subset of formulas that are dependent on volatile or changed cells. In Excel 2007 and later this sequence is calculated in a multi-threaded way.

So in practical terms trying to determine the calculation sequence in a large complex workbook is not a good idea.

For more information see http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsc.htm and associated pages

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That was an interesting link. Unfortunately it seems that I can only analyze the dependencies of one formula at a time. Getting a list which indicates the sequence seems not to be available, right?

Comment: Well you can get it if you want to decipher the calculation chain part in the XLSX file, but since its dynamic, not static, it will change at the next calculation even if none of the data/formulas change. Why do you want the information since it has no practical value?

Comment: For me it would be useful because I have a complex workbook that I need to build a server-side application from. But in my app I need to call the calculation steps in a defined order. So simply to know the order in which the cells are calculated would help me a lot.

Comment: So bif you want to part-duplicate the Excel calculation engine you can either use the Open XML documentation to decipher the calculation chain part (assuming the the workbook is 100% static) or build your own spreadsheet formula algorithm (inefficient ones can be fairly straightforward).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help.
I've opened the xlsx-file in a XML-editor and found the calcChain.xml inside the file. This xml contains the sequence of the calculations.
The elements of the calc chain are described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278336(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 1):

**Excel calculation order within formula**

Excel calculates in a specific way within each formula.  From the [Microsoft documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/calculation-operators-and-precedence-HP010078886.aspx) it will process from left to right but will process brackets (Aka parentheses) first.  Excel evaluates in order of [BODMAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

**Excel calculation order between formula**

Excel will determine which formula are independent of others and calculate those first.  This includes formulae referring to cells that only contain values or forumulae that reference constants or [volatile](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm) functions.

**Finding the processing sequence**

For starters, this is also known as tracing dependencies (and precedents).  In Excel, in the formula tab on the ribbon you can access the audit functions that allow you to trace dependents or precedents.  These will point you at the formulae that will be calculated before or after a given cell. This gives you the ability to step through the order so that you can ensure it's correct.  For more detail on this I recommend this [Microsoft article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/display-the-relationships-between-formulas-and-cells-HP010342448.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm currently using the "Trace Precedents" and "Trace Dependents" for analyzing one formula at a time. Seems that a sequence list is not available in Excel.